# java.lang.NullPointerException em sistema de chat

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2, primefaces, nullpointerexception

Eu estou fazendo um chat HelpDesk projeto com JSF 2.0 e Primefaces, mas é gerado um erro quando tento conectar o `Attendant` ou usuário no chat.

Em `atendente.xhtml` e `index.xhtml` tem um formulário que envia as informações para um `AtendenteBean.java` e `UsuarioBean.java`, respectivamente.

#### Atendente.jsp:

```
<p:panel header="Login do Atendente" rendered="#{not atendenteMB.autenticado}">
         <h:outputLabel for="txtNome" value="Login:"/>
         <br/>

         <h:inputText id="txtNome" value="#{atendenteMB.atendente.login}"/>
         <br/>

         <h:outputLabel for="txtSenha" value="Senha:"/>
         <br/>

         <h:inputSecret id="txtSenha" value="#{atendenteMB.atendente.senha}"/>
         <br/>
         <h:commandButton action="#{atendenteMB.signIn}" value="Entrar"/>
         <br/>

       </p:panel>
```

#### AtendenteBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean(name="atendenteMB")

@SessionScoped
public class AtendenteBean implements Serializable{

public AtendenteBean(){
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{localizadorMB}")
private LocalizadorBean gerenciarLocalizador;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{chatMB}")
private ChatBean chat;

private Atendente atendente = new Atendente();
private boolean autenticado;

public void signIn(){
    if(atendente.getLogin().equals(atendente.getSenha())){
        gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador().addAtendente(atendente);
        setAutenticado(true);
    }
    else{
        FacesMessage msgm = new FacesMessage("Login ou Senha inválidos.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msgm);
    }
```

### }

Erro gerado quando clico no botão Enviar.

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

type Exception report

message
---
java.lang.NullPointerException

description
---
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
---
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



root cause 
---
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpress    ionAdapter.java:101)
        com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



root cause
---

java.lang.NullPointerException
    managedbean.AtendenteBean.signIn(AtendenteBean.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpress    ionAdapter.java:87)
        com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

---

Se precisarem de mais detalhes, é só comentar.

Comment: O que tem na linha abaixo?:  managedbean.AtendenteBean.signIn(AtendenteBean.java:34)

Comment: Editei e deixei as partes dos códigos relevantes à pergunta.

Comment: A questão é, você tem um erro que aponta para a linha 34 do AtendenteBean. Qual o código dessa linha? E aí que está o problema.

Comment: Essa a baixo:

    public void signIn(){
            if(atendente.getLogin().equals(atendente.getSenha())){
                gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador().addAtendente(atendente    );
            setAutenticado(true);
        }
        else{
            FacesMessage msgm = new FacesMessage("Login ou     Senha inválidos.");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msgm);
        }
    }

Comment: Novamente, o que está na linha 34? É o if? O método todo está no código acima. É preciso saber o que está na linha 34 apenas.

Comment: A linha 34 começa em: gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador().addAtendente(atendente);
no campo de código eu coloquei esse método.

Comment: Beleza. Agora faça um DEBUG e veja quem está null aí. Tem muito objeto encadeado aí.

Comment: Eu não intendo mto de Debug, mas ele parou na linha 34 e informou o erro NullPointer e na linha de cima está selecionado de cor cinza o 'getSenha();'.

Comment: Como vejo quem está Null?, o getSenha() só estava selecionado de cinza pq eu tinha clicado nele, foi mal.

Comment: @Luiz qual IDE vc está usando? Eclipse, NetBeans?

Comment: Problema resolvido com o debug, obrigado ao Math por ajudar em outro tópico e ao @uaiHebert pela sugestão.
A variável **gerenciarLocalizador** estava Null, pois eu não a tinha instanciado na minha classe e o construtor do objeto tbm não inicializava corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug pra que te quero..

Mas olhando por cima, existem 3 linhas, dentro do método signIn() que podem estar referenciando referencias nulas:

1 - atendente.getLogin().equals(...)
2 - gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador().addAtendente(atendente)
3 - FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msgm)

Se getLogin(), getGerenciador() ou getCurrentInstance() voltarem uma referencia nula, não é possivel acessar métodos ou as propriedades do objeto, já que o mesmo, não esta onde deveria estar

Você pode resolver isso de duas formas: rodando um debug e checando o retorno de cada um desses 3 métodos acima, ou o que é mais indicado; aloque em variáveis locais dentro do escopo da função **signIn** e cheque pela nulidade do objeto antes de acessar os seus membros de forma aninhada como você fez.

```
Login l = atendente.getLogin();
if(l == null) {
 ... // imprime no console.. fonte do bug
  return; // retorna abruptamente
}

// ok, temos certeza que "f" existe
if (l.equals(...)) {...}

Gerenciador g = gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador();
if(g == null) {
 // imprime no console.. fonte do bug
 return; // retorna abruptamente
}

// ok, agora temos certeza que "g" existe
g.addAtendente(atendente);

FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()

if(context != null) { ... }
```

Se quiser depois que detectar qual desses volta nulo e corrigir o erro (faltaram ser criados em algum outro lugar), você pode voltar o seu código como estava, de forma aninhada se quiser, mas desde que os objetos sempre sejam garantidos de terem sido instanciados antes (embora não seja uma boa prática)

Comment: Eh, essa com certeza é uma boa prática para descobrir o elemento nulo. Não pensei nisso.
Mas pq não é uma boa prática instanciar objetos?

Comment: O que não é muito aconselhável, exatamente por voltar os tipos de erro ao qual você se deparou, é aninhar as dereferencias aos objetos na forma "x.getA().doB()" quando "getA()" retorna um objeto composto/classe ao invés de um valor simples como um inteiro..  O ideal é guardar em variaveis locais e reutilizar essa variavel local dentro do escopo. A unica exceção é quando se retorna objetos singleton em métodos estáticos como no caso de "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()" já que se supoe que dentro do metodo estático se instancie o objeto caso seja nulo, não tendo perigo de voltar 'null'

Comment: ata, o correto seria então aninhar variáveis ao invés de métodos, poderia até testá-las no try..catch para tratar a exceção do nullPointer... O aninhamento ficaria `if (l.equals(s)) {...}`, sendo l do `getLoguin()` e s de `getSenha()`.

Comment: o "atendente.getSenha()" não tem problema algum, seria até indicado usar direto nesse caso por questões de legibilidade do código..  o "atendente.getLogin().equals()" também poderia passar, já que entende-se que é uma string e que não deve ser nulo em hipótese alguma..  já o "gerenciarLocalizador.getGerenciador().addAtendente(atendente)" pode ser problema, mas tambem poderia ser usado apenas se "getGerenciador()" fosse estático o que não é o caso como vi no código, nesse caso sim, aloca em uma variável local, pra depois executar o "addAtendente()" vai te ajudar inclusive no debug.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e pelas dicas!