# Como usar o debug no Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debug

Estou tendo um problema muito chato com um erro java.lang.NullPointerException e gostaria de saber se com o debug ele mostra qual elemento é null, ao invés de dizer somente em que linha está o erro.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Primeiro, marque um *breakpoint* na linha de código que você tem o problema. No seu caso é na [linha 34](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4898/3117), correto? :)

Para inserir o *breakpoint* dê dois cliques no lado esquerdo da indicação do número da linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai ficar uma bolinha azul. Depois, ao invés de clicar na seta branca dentro do círculo verde para rodar o programa, clique no *bug* (inseto) a sua esquerda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu programa vai rodar normalmente até o momento que a execução atingir uma linha que estiver marcada com um *breakpoint*. Se for a primeira vez que roda no modo debug, o Eclipse lhe perguntará se deseja mudar a perspectiva para Debug, conforme a tela abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em *Yes*. Se preferir marque a caixa de seleção para ele lembrar da sua escolha.

Toda vez que a execução se deparar com um *breakpoint*, ela será momentaneamente interrompida e você poderá ver o conteúdo das variáveis naquele momento.

Para ver o conteúdo das variáveis você pode pairar o cursor por cima do nome de cada uma delas, ou pode também adicioná-las à janela `Expressions` para ver o conteúdo de várias variáveis ao mesmo tempo. Para adicionar uma variável a essa janela, selecione a variável e clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre ela, depois clique em `watch`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela(s) aparecerá(ão) assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir do momento que a execução do código se deparar com um *breakpoint* você poderá continuar a execução linha-por-linha, pode entrar ou não em métodos, ou mesmo saindo de métodos, a partir de então. Existem as opções correspondentes na barra de tarefas. Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no primeiro símbolo, que é a seta verde, você vai passar o comando para seu programa rodar até encontrar outro *breakpoint*. O quadrado vermelho interrompe por completo a execução do seu código. A primeira seta amarela (cuja tecla de atalho é o F5) vai executar linha por linha do seu código entrando nos métodos quando houver um, inclusive mudando a tela para mostrar a classe correspondente, acredito que essa pode ser uma boa opção para o seu caso. A segunda seta amarela é quando você deseja executar linhar por linhas mas sem entrar em um método quando encontrar um. Já a última seta amarela é a opção de cair fora do método atual.

O console vai te dar mais detalhes quando a exceção ocorrer, fique de olho e bom *debug*.

Comment: Obrigado! Agora consigo ver os valores das variáveis.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, há muito tempo que estou com esse erro e o debug rapidamente me apontou a variável que estava Null.

Comment: No meu eclipse não tem a aba expression. Oque fazer?

Comment: @MarcosGuimarães Certifique-se de que a perspectiva está no modo Debug, depois clique em Window > Show View > Expressions.