# Atualizar o valor obtido em um EditText

Tags: java, android, null

Seguinte, estou tendo um problema ao pegar o valor em um EditText e exibí-lo em um TextView. O valor exibido ao se usar uma string, é "null", e ao usar int, é 0. Acredito que isso aconteça porque o valor que está sendo coletado, é o que aparece antes do digitado, ou seja, nada!

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de monitorar o valor digitado no EditText para que quando ele for alterado, o botão colete o novo valor, e não o anterior, se esse for o problema.

[image: Um exemplo do valor obtido]

O código da classe responsável pelo cálculo está [aqui](http://pastebin.com/WhGF2XsJ).

Edit.: Bastou chamar o método dentro do evento de Click do botão.

```
btnCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
                        btnCalc.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
                    { 
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {      
                                Calculate(); //este método
                                result = "#" + rst1 + remainderR + rst2 + remainderG + rst3 + remainderB;
                                txtResult.setText(result);     
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: edita e coloca o código que você fez pra calcular

Comment: Pronto, atualizei.

Comment: @leo.saldanha Você tem que começar a usar o debug, você elimina inúmeros erros com essa prática. Do jeito que está é realmente muito difícil alguém te ajudar. Sugestão: [Como usar o debug no Eclipse?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4923/3117)

Comment: você não chamou o método calcular

Comment: Amigo tens de fazer o calculo dentro do onClick, senão não será considerada a função que calcula.

Comment: Mas o onClick fica dentro do onCreate, o que fica totalmente inviável, visto que o método não aceita códigos muito extensos.

Comment: Vou começar a usar o debug, apesar de acreditar que não seja o caso. Obrigado.

Comment: leo, chama simplesmente ao função `Calculate()` dentro do onClick antes de apresentar o resultado. Não é para pores a função lá dentro toda.

Comment: Vê aqui: http://pastebin.com/bT4i9MMk

Comment: Obrigado Jorge. Só faltava isso. Peço desculpas a vocês pela pergunta boba, mas comecei a programar há pouco tempo e acabo esquecendo de coisas como essas. :/

Comment: Estamos aqui é para ajudar, tenta fazer sempre debug para saberes o que está a correr mal. Com o tempo vais ganhando prática :)

Comment: Oi @LeonardoSaldanha! Já que a pergunta foi concluída, você poderia editar a pergunta, para colocar o trecho do código com problema, sem a necessidade de que as pessoas tenham que acessar um link externo?

Comment: Pronto, @carlosrafaelgn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As variáveis estão **NULL** porque elas só são inicializadas no método `Calculate()`, que não está sendo chamado quando o botão é clicado.

Answer (score 1):

Peguei este código em outro fórum, acredito que possa ser útil para você:

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Basicamente ele monitora um edit e quando o usuário clica em enter retorna a informação.

Segue o link para os créditos:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/como-acessar-funccoes-do-campo-edittext-onenter-setfocus/446366