# Valor estranho ao imprimir array

Tags: java, array, printf, print

Em `java`, estou tendo dificuldades em entender alguns conceitos.

**Em uma página .jsp, tenho o seguinte código:**

> String[] arrayRegioes =
>   request.getParameterValues("numRegiaoUsuario");//objeto

Quando imprimo o array, o valor mostrado é:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5a879b45
```

Gostaria de saber o que significa esse valor, porque não consigo visualizar o valor dele, já que passei o seguinte conteúdo:

```
[*, adm, r1]
```

Comment: Como você está imprimindo esse valor?

Comment: System.out.print("arrayRegioes: " + arrayRegioes);

Comment: Agora sua pergunta mudou radicalmente. A resposta nem serve mais.

Comment: Diego, eu crio uma pergunta nova. Preciso muito dessa ajuda. Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: @durtto Sugiro reverter sua pergunta ao que estava antes e fazer uma nova. Pelo menos essa vai servir para quem mais tiver a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está vendo é a representação padrão de objetos Java, ou seja, de exemplares de classes que não implementam `toString()`. Vetores fazem parte desse grupo.

Não consigo ver por que você gostaria de imprimir um vetor a não ser para fins de depuração. Nesse caso, use um depurador. Depuradores costumam ter um modo de visualização de vetores e outros objetos enumeráveis e costumam listar os elementos exatamente igual você está querendo. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4923/como-usar-o-debug-no-eclipse/4924#4924) tem algumas instruções de como usar um depurador no Eclipse. Nas outras IDEs é bastante parecido.

Caso realmente queira imprimir o valor do vetor, seja lá qual for o motivo, supondo que você está usando `System.out.println()` para isso, basta fazer:

```
for (String regiao : arrayRegioes) {
    System.out.println(regiao);
}
```

Dessa forma, você está percorrendo os elementos do vetor (chamando-os de `regiao`) e exibindo.

Comment: Vou complementar minha pergunta, você vai entender onde quero chegar.

Comment: Uma forma alternativa é fazer `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayRegioes))`. Será impresso `[*, adm, r1]` em vez de `[Ljava.lang.String;@5a879b45`.

Comment: @Piovezan Não sabia dessa. Dá uma boa resposta!

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Criada :)

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim:

```
for(String regioes : arrayRegioes){

System.out.print("arrayRegioes: " + regioes);
}
```

Comment: Vou complementar minha pergunta, você vai entender onde quero chegar.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma compacta de imprimir o array como desejado é fazer uso do método utilitário `Arrays.toString()`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayRegioes));
```

Será impresso `[*, adm, r1]` em vez da representação-padrão `[Ljava.lang.String;@5a879b45`.